# How to set a value on a table field with symfony 1.4

Tags: php, ajax, database, forms, symfony-1.4

I'm passing a value with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:  "http://juego.local/frontend_dev.php/espacio/salvaPuntos",
   data: { puntos: 123 }
});
```

I need to update a table field with it. This is what i'm doing ("symfony side"):

```
public function executeSalvaPuntos(sfWebRequest $request) 
{

  $this->puntosEspacio  = $request->getParameter('puntos');
  $this->jugador        = Doctrine::getTable('Jugador')->findOneByEmail($this->getUser()->getUsername());
  $this->puntos         = $this->jugador->getPuntosJuegos() + $this->puntosEspacio;

  $this->form   = new JugadorForm($this->jugador);
  $this->form->setDefault('puntos_juegos', $this->puntos);
  $this->processForm($request, $this->form);
}
```

Here's also my JugadorForm:

```
public function configure()
{

  unset($this['email'],
        $this['nombre'],
        $this['apellido'],
        $this['puntaje_total'],
        $this['fecha_ult_log'],
        $this['foto_perfil_url']
  );

  $this->setWidgets(array(
    'puntos_juegos'      => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden()
  ));

  $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('Jugador[%s]');

  $this->setValidators(array(
    'puntos_juegos'      => new sfValidatorInteger()
  ));   
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->jugador = Doctrine::getTable('Jugador')->findOneByEmail($this->getUser()->getUsername());
$this->jugador->puntos_juegos += $request->getParameter('puntos');
$this->jugador->puntos_juegos->save();
```

Comment: In the last line you have unnecessary `puntos_juegos`, it should be `$this->jugador->save()`. Anyway I give +1 as it's a good solution. @gabrielM There is no need to use the form if you're editing the object directly. You should use forms when you let the webusers edit your objects.